# javascript access global variable in module type script

Tags: javascript

I've a

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"> </script>
```

in my html and index.js has

```
var present = "default";

document.querySelector("#link").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    present = e.target;
});
```

I wanted to investigate the event variable with the browser console. and tried to access `present` and returns `undefined`
is there any way I can accesss those virables in my module script using the console in my browser developer tools? i need this to debug my app through the console.

I can't even access the variable `present` to get `"default"`

Comment: `present` is not a global variable, if it's declared in a script type of module. However, `present` seems to be in the outer scope of the event handler, then there's no problems, you just haven't assign a value to `present` variable.

Comment: @Teemu, it gets value when the event gets triggered. but even after that I can't access its content.<br><br> even with a default value, I can't access the variable at all.

Comment: You need to learn what `module` means. Module does not have global variables.

Comment: @epascarello so does it mean I can't debug it using my browser's console?

Comment: It should be available when you change the context in your developer tools.

Comment: @epascarello thank you, I'll need to read how to do that then...

Comment: If you can change the content of the script there are some ways (1) set global variable (2) add `debugger;` there (3) set a break point in the developer console.